# Why we can write the $span(\vec{u},\vec{v}) = \{ x \in R^3 : \vec{A}\vec{x} = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am just learning some linear algebra from some video from youtube. So, they mentioned we can write $Span(\vec{u},\vec{v})$ as :
$Span(\vec{u},\vec{v}) = \{ x \in R^3 : \vec{A}\cdot\vec{x} = 0\}$. Why is this true ?

Comment: Care to link to the video?

Comment: @Clayton https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcHFb8V5U_4&index=12&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd

Comment: As the person who *made* the video, I will answer that the video shows you how. The rigorous proof that it is always possible (when $\vec u, \vec v$ are non-parallel) will come from the notion of dimension later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the two vectors $u$ and $v$ are elements of the matrix $A$'s null space. That being said, apparently the two vectors $u$ and $v$ span the matrix's null space, so for any $x\in\mathbb R^3$ with $Ax = 0$, there exist scalars $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $x = c_1u + c_2v$. So any vector in $\text{null}\ A$ can be written as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.